# Debug\App.g.i.cs and Debug\App.g.cs are identical---what's going on here?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio

WPF projects in Visual Studio auto-generate `Debug\App.g.i.cs` and `Debug\App.g.cs` files. These files are identical. What's happening here? Does the `i` stand for "interactive" such that one copy is slapped around by Visual Studio (design-time) and the other is used for running the "real" build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am also new to wpf...
When going with basics i found one article on WPF

In that it was mentioned "i" as intellisence..
if u want go with this following link

http://stuff.seans.com/2008/07/11/hello-wpf-world-part-1/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the `i` stands for, but the `*.g.i.<language-extension>` files are generated by the compiler as temporary files.